# ZK - changing the default position of the Error message in UI

Tags: java, css, eclipse, zk

I'm still very new to ZK framework. I'm attempting to change the position of the error box as shown in the attached image to a new position (somewhere below the textbox). I was wondering if it was possible. If so, how? I was not able to find the css file which has the information on the features of the error popup.

[image: change the default position of the Error message]

Comment: Check for Css Class in Inspect element by searching `Please enter`

Comment: Look for ZK framework Specifications, if there is some prebuilt property to change the position of error msg.

Comment: I've done that already. but the class it's mentioning don't have the properties that i see during runtime in any of the css files. That's why I wanted to know if it was possible to change the position of the error popup

Comment: Then try giving some new properties to the class, like `top: 10px;`

Comment: It's a slippery slope to start adjusting that CSS - if I'm not mistaken, the error message displays in different locations depending on available space. If that's the case, shifting it 10px one way may help in some cases and make things worse in others.